# Linux server goes unresponsive and cannot figure out why?

Tags: linux, rhel

When server goes unresponsive (cannot ping or ssh) even console (accessed via ipmitool) is either blank with no output or unresponsive as well. If I reset/soft power cycle the host, it comes up fine and, both server and console works fine. What I have noticed so far during my investigation:

1. I see no server load of any kind (CPU, memory, I/O, etc.)
2. Don't see any error on /var/log/messages
3. Once the host is unresponsive, it stops updating messages file
4. See no hardware issues
5. Some hosts does this very often (like daily)
6. Obviously this is not due to network issue

Any suggestion on how to go about resolving this issue is highly appreciated. Any tools or logs, that I can use will also be very helpful. We got no vendor support.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest enabling the `kdump` service, and allow the serial console through ipmi to initiate a crashdump via [Magic Sysrq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) (crashdump is ‘c’).

With a saved kernel crashdump, you can inspect what was going on while it was stuck.

Since you already have ipmi, you could also set up the SOL device as the console in the kernel parameters, so you could just leave that running. Sending syslog to a remote host is also a good idea.